# How to make force a user to enter some numbers, before they choose from a menu?

Tags: c++, menu, console

I've got a menu system with different menu numbers.

The user has to choose option 1 first, before he can use options 2 to 5.

How can I implement this error message?

Here is my simplified code:

```
do{
switch(menu){
          case 1:
              cout<<"Input "<<input<< "numbers: ";
              for(int i=0;i<input;input++){
                           listInput(&array[i]) }}
              cout<<"\n\nEnter r/R to return to the menu: ";
              cin>>r;
              system("cls");
                    break;
          case 2:
              cout<<"Calculate Sum";                 //if menu!=case 1 first
              //my operations                        //cout<<"Error message";
               break;                                //something like this??
          default:
              cout<<"Invalid Input";
               }}                              
               while(r=='r'||r=='R');
```

Comment: Format you code please

Answer (score 4):

If inputting numbers is mandatory, just don't give the user option to do it wrong. One option would be to move the case 1 code into a `getnumbers` function and do something like;

```
getnumbers(&array);    // Force the user to input numbers before getting the 
                       // option to select the wrong option
...menu input

do {
    switch(menu){
      case 1:
          getnumbers(&array);
          break;
      case 2:
          cout<<"Calculate Sum";                 //if menu!=case 1 first
          //my operations                        //cout<<"Error message";
           break;                 
...
```

Comment: +1 This makes the user experience more pleasant and is also easier to handle in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

create a global variable (say flag) and set it to 0.
In case 1, set the variable to 1 (`flag = 1`)
In the rest of the cases, if flag is not 1, just display an error and break.

```
do{
int flag = 0;
switch(menu){
          case 1:

              cout<<"Input "<<input<< "numbers: ";
              for(int i=0;i<input;input++){
                           listInput(&array[i]) }}
              cout<<"\n\nEnter r/R to return to the menu: ";
              cin>>r;
              system("cls");
              flag = 1;
                    break;
          case 2:
              if (flag == 0)
              {
                  cout <<"Choose 1 first";
                  break;
              }
              cout<<"Calculate Sum";                 //if menu!=case 1 first
              //my operations                        //cout<<"Error message";
               break;                                //something like this??
          default:
              cout<<"Invalid Input";
               }}                              
               while(r=='r'||r=='R');
```

Comment: This is also known as a `state machine`, it does different things according to some flag(s).